# how to change the closing of a dialog box

Tags: jquery

I want to change the closing behavior of my dialog box

I found on this site
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated

an animated dialog box
when you close it, it explodes
I wish it could close on its way to the top corner without bursting

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    }
  });
  $("#opener").on("click", function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the &apos;x&apos; icon.</p>
</div>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

Comment: Did you checked that page : https://jqueryui.com/effect/ ?

Answer (score 0):

### You can do the following:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
          effect: "blind",
          duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
          effect: "blind",
          duration: 1000
        }
      });

      $("#opener").on("click", function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the &apos;x&apos; icon.</p>
  </div>

  <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>


</body>

</html>
```

**Here I removed the `explode` effect when closing the dialog box and replaced it with `blind`.**

Comment: Thanks for the code but the box does not move when closing and while closing towards the upper right corner